# Apps does not return back after calling OnStartActivityResult

Tags: android, image, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have an activity which I use to call Intent to pick image from the gallery.
Returns to home screen directly after selecting the image and the gallery intent tries to go back to my Activity which is not found i think.

```
public void startScan(View view) { 

    Intent intent = new     Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONT    ENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 99);
    }
```

Mainfest:

```
<application
tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:persistent="true"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="מערכת דיווחים"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible|adjust    Pan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible|adjust    Pan" >
</activity>
</application>
```

OnActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent      data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getExtras().getParcelable(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),     uri);
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
           pushbutton.setText(bitmap.getByteCount());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: post code of your other activity , how u set and pass the data back there

Comment: in other activity call somewhere... Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
or you can send setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCEL, resultIntent);

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: There is no other activity, I am trying to pick an image from gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your onActivityResult:

```
Uri originalUri = data.getData();
                final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |      Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
String selectedImagePath = getPath(context,originalUri );
```

and below is getPath(context, Uri)

```
 public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The problem that is onActivityResult is not called at all